# Append and remove the value of checkbox into an array state in Reactjs

Tags: arrays, reactjs, checkbox

I am using mui checkbox component and this is how I'm displaying it:

```
 <FormControl component="fieldset">
    <FormGroup aria-label="position" column>
        {sortedData.map((obj) => {
            return (
                <FormControlLabel
                    value="type"
                    control={<Checkbox color="primary"/>}
                    label={obj}
                    name={obj}
                    onChange={handleTypeCheckboxChange}
                    labelPlacement="end"
                />
            );
        })}
    </FormGroup>
</FormControl>
```

Now on this function handleTypeCheckboxChange I want to add or remove the values of the checkboxes when the user checks or unchecks.

This is how I tried to do but it isn't working. It gives me NaN:

```
const [typeValue, setTypeValue] = useState([]) // the state array where I wanna store the checkbox checked values

const handleTypeCheckboxChange = (event) => {

    let typeValuesArray = []
    let index

    if (event.target.checked) {
        setTypeCheckboxCount(prevState => prevState + 1)
        typeValuesArray.push(+(event.target.name))
    } else {
        setTypeCheckboxCount(prevState => prevState - 1)
        index = typeValuesArray.indexOf(+(event.target.name))
        typeValuesArray.splice(index, 1)
    }

    setTypeValue(typeValuesArray)
}
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: you should reproduce this on codesandbox so other would catch up more easily

Answer (score 0):

Remove the + sign from `push` and `indexOf` methods argument.
Because:
`+'anystring' = NaN`

Comment: ok so I removed itt, but it isnt appending the value or removing it correctly

Comment: there's always only one value in the array, and when I uncheck any of the boxes the array size becomes 0. even though some other boxes are checked.

Comment: `setTypeValue([...typeValue, event.target.name])` is antipattern. You should not use state for its own update. Instead use `setTypeValue(prevTypes => [...prevTypes, event.target.name])

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted solution on behalf of the question author, to move the answer to the answer space)*.

This was solved. I changed my code to this:

```
 const handleTypeCheckboxChange = (event, index) => {


        if (event.target.checked) {
            setTypeCheckboxCount(prevState => prevState + 1)
            
            setTypeValue([...typeValue, event.target.name])
        } else {
            setTypeCheckboxCount(prevState => prevState - 1)
            
            setTypeValue(
                typeValue.filter( v => v !== event.target.name)
            )


        }

        
    }
```